# Windows 7 doesn't load all drivers. Seems a faux Safe Mode-Not Safe Mode

Tags: windows-7, drivers, multi-boot

When I start up Windows 7 the resolution is 800x600 or some sort of low resolution, but not the *1366x768* i am used to.
What's worse, the mouse doesn't work. There's no internet.

It's a dual booted system with Win7 and Win10. Under Win10 the mouse, the resolution and everything work fine. 
The Win10 partition was added later with a cloning app. And I used an BCD editor to add the partition and edit the boot menu.

Question: 
**How do I get Windows 7 to load every driver?**

It almost seems like *Safe Mode*, but it is not, since it doesn't have the word *"Safe Mode"* in the 4 corners of the screen.

History: I rescued the SSD from another laptop, so of course it might be that certain hardware issues are there, but considering that:

- A. It's Win7, it should be able to work with standard issue laptop of
  well known brands
- B. The laptop has supported Win7 before, when that was installed on its original HDD (sadly deceased)

If it's not obvious by now: the **OBJECT** is to avoid re-installing Win7 and all the applications that are on it.

Comment: Swapping hard drives from other hardware configurations rarely works, it does not have all the drivers for the new hardware. Check device manager for drivers that are missing.

Comment: If it rarely works, how do you explain the Windows 10 partition working A-OK?
But that's a good tip, I will reboot into Win 7.

Comment: W10 is not W7, W10 has more onboard drivers than 7 and copes better with severe hardware changes.